# Laravel's Blade template @yield and @section how does it work?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, view, laravel-blade

I'm new to Laravel and want to learn how to use the Blade template system properly, but i cant wrap my head around the difference between @section and @yield. 
I've been reading the docs : https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade.

But it's not explaining the differences and how to use them properly.
I've been reading posts in other forums too like this one :

https://laravel.io/forum/09-02-2014-using-section-and-yield

But still i'm a bit confused.

For example right now i'm creating an app that have multiple pages with commun pieces between them, so for now i get that i have to create a common layout for this pages, but when to use @section and when do i have to use @yield ?

for example if i have a page like so :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Name') }}</title>
    //Common CSS between pages
    <link href="{{ asset('css/style1.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    //Changing CSS between pages
    <link href="{{ asset('css/style2.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    //the content stay the same !
    <div id="app">
        <span id="some_style">hello world !</span>
    </div>
    <script>
       //common JS
       <script src="{{ asset('script1.js') }}">
       //Changing JS between pages
       <script src="{{ asset('script2.js') }}">
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can i organise it using the blade templating?

Comment: `@yield` in your "parent" template, use `@extends` and `@section` in the child templates. More about [template inheritance](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#template-inheritance). Also, don't place `<script>` tags in `<script>` tags. And: `<!-- -->` is used for HTML comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you 2 templates. Lets call one `Base.blade.php` and the other one `Posts.blade.php`.

We'll `@extends('base')` in `Posts`.

Using `@section` in `Posts` and `@yield` in `Base`.

Something like this:

```
Base

@yield('posts') {# the section called "posts" #}


Posts

@extends('base')

@section('posts')
   Here be posts
@endsection
```

Whatever is written in `posts` will be `yielded` in the base blade.

Think of it as inheritance.

You can imagine it as classes if you will. Where the child class calls a method in the base class.

```
class Base {
    protected function printSomething($something) {
        echo $something;
    }
}


class Posts extends Base {
    public function BaseWillPrint() {
        $this->printSomething('POSTS');
    }
}
```

Basically I haven't told you anything that doesn't already exist in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but what if posts have multiple inherances ? how can i use them in multiple templates?

Comment: I'm gonna need an example of what you're thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, assuming if you have a template you can make the base of template in `layouts/app.blade/php` and you can make the `@yield('anything')` and then in your `views/main.blade.php` you must give `@extends('layouts.app')` and

```
@section('anything')
*for dynamic page
@endsection
```